# ggplot2 - legend for combined geom_point and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am given a data set and would like to plot one variable as points and the others as lines with different line types (each variable in a distinct colour).

```
 a <- c(10:20)
 df <- data.frame(a=a,b=a,c=a*a/10,d=10*sqrt(a))
 df_melt <- reshape2::melt(df,id.vars='a')

 ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=a,y=value,colour=variable,linetype=variable,shape=variable))+
           geom_line(data=subset(df_melt,variable == "b"))+
           geom_line(data=subset(df_melt,variable == "c"))+
           geom_point(data=subset(df_melt,variable == "d"))
```

This yields now the wanted plot:

[image]

Yet, the legend now shows linetypes and shapes for all three variables, although not all variables actual display them.

How can I remove line type or shape accordingly to make the legend consistent with the plot display?

Comment: You may want to use guides() function:
[guides documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.1.0/topics/guides)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if you find yourself adding multiple `geom_line()` or `geom_point()` layers with different subsets -- there's usually a better way that involves manipulating the variables directly.  Here I've done it by adding `NA` values for points or lines respectively (in `scale_linetype_manual()` or `scale_shape_manual()`) when they should be missing. (The shapes/linetypes used aren't exactly the same as the ones you used above, but that's easy enough to adjust.)

```
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=a,y=value,colour=variable,
                    linetype=variable,shape=variable))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()+
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,NA))+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(NA,NA,2))
```

Comment: This now requires string values, e.g. `scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed",NA))`.

Comment: It does? I'm on `ggplot2` 3.4.2 and it seems to be working; did it change recently?

Comment: In `R version 4.2.3` with `ggplot2_3.4.2`, I get the error _Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_lines, x$x, x$y, index, x$arrow) : invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8_ otherwise.

Comment: oops, you're right. I don't know what I was doing before.  I get this now. I might post a ggplot issue  because I can't see anything explicit about line types in the ggplot [NEWS file](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#ggplot2-342).